# Cómo puedo hacer que un botón haga scroll a cualquier parte de la página?

Tags: javascript, funciones, botón, scroll

Algo parecido al scorllTop, pero poder elegir donde quiero que vaya el scroll

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: '0px'
    }, 300);
});
```

});

Comment: `window.scrollTo(x, y)` tal vez?

Answer (score 2):

Puede que te interese el método `scrollIntoView`

[Aquí tienes el enlace para consultarlo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp)

Te dejo el ejemplo que proporciona [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) para una mejor representación visual.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  margin:500px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: coral;
  position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the buttons to scroll to the top or to the bottom of the element with id="content".</p>

<button onclick="scrollToTop()">Scroll to the top of the element</button>
<button onclick="scrollToBottom()">Scroll to the bottom of the element</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="content">
  <div style="position:absolute;top:0;">Some text at the top</div>
  <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0">Some text at the bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");

function scrollToTop() {
  elmnt.scrollIntoView(true); // Top
}

function scrollToBottom() {
  elmnt.scrollIntoView(false); // Bottom
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```